# howto find our the current language which the user has selected on his WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

howto find our the current language which the user has selected on his WP7?

need to find out for a app which language the user is using, like english, german or french.

how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the current culture by using the [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) static property.

Comment: See also "How to: Build a Localized Application for Windows Phone" - [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520(v=VS.92).aspx)