# How to get the Windows Phone system language from code?

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, lang

Solution:
**Use CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture**

User can change the system language of Windows Phone at:
Settings > language+region > Phone language

How can I get the selected language (Phone language) from C# code?

Below is my phone settings:

[image]

Here is my code snippet:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
    "*************************************   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name = " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString() + ", "  +
    "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo = " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo + ", " +
    "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName = " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName + ", " +
    "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.EnglishName = " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.EnglishName + ", " +
    "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name = " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name + ", " +
    "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NativeName = " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NativeName + ", " +
    "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo = " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo
);
```

Here is the output:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name = zh-HK,
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo = CompareInfo - zh-HK,
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName = Chinese (Traditional, Hong
Kong SAR), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.EnglishName = Chinese
(Traditional, Hong Kong SAR), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name = zh-HK,
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NativeName = 中文(香港特別行政區),
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo = TextInfo - zh-HK
```

I cannot find the 'Phone Language'

Comment: possible duplicate of [howto find our the current language which the user has selected on his WP7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405128/howto-find-our-the-current-language-which-the-user-has-selected-on-his-wp7)

Comment: Hi Emo, I have updated my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. It should correctly reflect the phone language.

Comment: Thanks Claus, seems that System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo is what I am looking for.

Comment: Just found that System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture is not work for WP8. The solution is use CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture instead.

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture returns wrong result at my Nokia 920 (WP8). Actually, the same result as using CultureInfo.CurrentCulture. Only CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture works on my device

Comment: CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture is two different things. You might want to look it up.

Comment: If I'm getting the Phone Language property I can only get that to work using CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture. And that was also the original question...

Comment: The UI language can differ from the platform language. As I've mentioned before, MSDN can clarify the difference for you in case you don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

you can check my answer, this will help you to change the language at runtime: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131401/2467917