# How do I change localization in C# on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, localization, windows-phone

I have my Resource files with 2 languages and my app already reads the values of one of them.  I would like to be able to change the language of my app (use the other resource file) in C# instead of changing the language of the whole phone in Settings.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Good question, although I don't know about windows phone, have you tried setting the current culture on the thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `App.xaml.cs`, in the `InitializePhoneApplication` method:

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    .......
}
```

The limitation is that it needs to be in the app initialization, so if the user changes the language, a restart will be required for it to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I'll be experimenting to see if it can be done in another method. I guess that once the tread has started with a Culture, the only way to change the Culture would be restarting it...

Answer (score 4):

you can do this without need to restart by reloading the page where the user change a language and maintaining the RTL/LTR of your page layout

I added this function in App.xaml.cs

```
public static void ChangeAppLanguage(string CultureName)
    {
        App.RootFrame.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureName);
        FlowDirection flow = (FlowDirection)Enum.Parse(typeof(FlowDirection), AppResources.ResourceFlowDirection);
        App.RootFrame.FlowDirection = flow;
        App.Current.RootVisual.UpdateLayout();
        App.RootFrame.UpdateLayout();
        var ReloadUri =( App.RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage).NavigationService.CurrentSource;
        (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri(ReloadUri + "?no-cache=" + Guid.NewGuid(), UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

where the CultureName like this : "ar-SA", "en-US"

and I called like this

```
private void EnglishMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        try
        {
            if(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "en-US")
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
            else
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

            AppResources.Culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

            App.ChangeAppLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);

            //this._contentLoaded = false; //this way does not refresh appBar
            //this.InitializeComponent();

            //this way work for one time only => if user change language more thane once the api does NOT call constructor
            //NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri("/PhoneApp2;component/MainPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error:\n\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dear Zakaria,

i tried your provided solution. Its not working inplace its creating the history on per click e.g. if i 5 times tried to change language and than i want to go back than me have to press back button of emulator 5 times than i will be able to go back. and its not tranlating. but it was seeming the superb approach.