# How to restart an application?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm going to change my app's language.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

but the problem is that it needs the application to be restarted. Is it possible to restart the app? (or is it possible to change the language without restarting?)

Comment: Why would you run the application in another culture than the phone is configured to? However, check if fr-FR is added as Supported culture in the manifest file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to force a restart of an application, also changing the language of a running app is pretty complicated. Here's what I would do:

1. Default to the OSs culture (standard behavior)
2. If required, allow the user to change the language in the app and make sure the override happens in the App.xaml.cs constructor
3. If a user changes the language, which is a scenario that doesn't occur often, show a popup that explains that a restart of the app is required. This is an approach that I took in a few apps and users are fine with that solution. It saves the huge effort of changing language "on-the-fly"

Good luck and let us know what you ended up doing!

Comment: agreed, this should be the way. i have the same problem here. My application language can be changed apart of the phone's language so i just declared an isolatedmemory key for language. my question is where and what object should i initialize with the string like "ar-SA" that will work throughout the application on next app start.

Comment: do i need to initialize to appManager object that resides statically in appResource class?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't change the language without restart avoiding additional code in you case. There is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093791/how-do-i-change-localization-in-c-sharp-on-windows-phone) of how to do it without restart, but things get a little bit more complicated here.