# Windows Phone 8.1 manually change resource file in code behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing application which requires for me to handle multiculture and resources in Windows Phone 8.1.

Currently it loads en language if my phone language is set to english, if I change it to french or whatever it also works. What i would like to do is for a user to be able to change the language in the app while not changing the language in the phone. I would like to have a settings page when user can pick language from a list of possibilities. Save it in some storage settings and after application start to load appropriate resources.

What I can't figure out is how to load specific resources based on some settings in the storage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change localization in C# on Windows Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093791/how-do-i-change-localization-in-c-sharp-on-windows-phone)

Comment: This helped me a lot : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378641

Answer (score 0):

Use [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to store the user selected language string.

When the app is loaded you can change the language to that selected by user using the

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride
```

Property.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you some details.
Create a class as `LacalizedStrings.cs` in your project.
And let's put that the resource file name is `AppResources`

```
public class LocalizedStrings
    {
        private static AppResources _localizedResources = new AppResources();
        public AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return _localizedResources; } }
    }
```

in your `AppResources` put one key as `ResourceLanguage` and value as `en-US`.

Now this value you can save in `IsolatedStorage` and the time of

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
}
```

or

```
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

you can check this value from `IsolatedStorage` and use it.

Hope it helps.