# How to get the current language from windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to get the current language. I have try like this.

```
  Console.WriteLine("Tese 1==> " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.EnglishName);
Console.WriteLine("Test 2==> " + CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.EnglishName);
```

Here i getting output like `English(United States)`.

But i want only 'English'. How to get the language alone.

Now i use other method to get the Output.

```
currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.EnglishName;
            string[] values = currentCulture.Split('(').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("Language ==> " + values.ElementAt(0));
```

Is there any default method to get the current language alone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518411/how-to-get-the-windows-phone-system-language-from-code

Comment: I have already tried this. `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. But output is :- `en-US`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the neutral culture from your `CurrentCulture` and use it's name:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
if (!culture.IsNeutralCulture) 
    culture = culture.Parent;
Console.WriteLine(culture.EnglishName);
```

For example for "en-us" or "en-gb" the parent culture is "en" with the name "English".

Comment: Thank you..!! It's working. May i know what is `culture.IsNeutralCulture`?

Comment: @Vijay `IsNeutralCulture` reflects the division of cultures into specific and neutral. Specific cultures contain additional information about country/region.

Answer (score 0):

Look here : [How to get the Windows Phone system language from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518411/how-to-get-the-windows-phone-system-language-from-code)

Original Answer:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately You can not have it directly. you would get the culture name in the format `language (country/region)` by using `DisplayName` Property `or` the culture name in the format `languagecode-country/regioncode` by using `Name` Property. for Getting Your Desired Output you are needed to `manipulate` the String what you are Getting from Properties.